# Youtube's Picture-in-Picture (PIP), but more options/features?

Tags: windows, media-player, youtube

I really love the new PIP for youtube vids. I had been using VLC for youtube and other videos to date and setting it up like in the screenshot. But you are stuck with those giant ugly title bars, windows 10 lets u kill the side padding but that doesn't fix the problem. So the PIP is really wonderful in that respect, however it's really limited in what u can do with it atm.

Is there anything out there right now that mimicks what youtube has achieved in terms of just having a free floating picture without menu's clogging up the screen? I guess a media player in general would be the desired, but something to make windows not put a giant ugly titlebar on things would work, or extensions for existing players would be good too. The desire is to use a single monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [VLC Skins](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.html) you can either find a minimal one that you like or design your own using the [Skin Editor](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skineditor.html).

*Note that Skins do not work on OS-X*